# Extract binary class vector from string label Python

Tags: python

I have a number of labeled classes - 'Class A' to 'Class H'. I would like to extract a binary vector given a labeled string

```
'Class A' -> [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

'Class G' -> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Etc. Is there a pythonic way of doing this? I could do it with a number of if-statements but is there a shorter way with only a few lines of code?

Answer (score 1):

You can to this using `ord` offset by the `ord` of `A`:

```
def class_string_to_vector(class_str):
    _idx = ord(class_str.strip()[-1].upper()) - ord('A')
    _vec = [0] * 8
    _vec[_idx] = 1
    return vec
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class_arr = ['Class A','Class B','Class C','Class D', 'Class E', 'Class F', 'Class G','Class H']
output = [ 1 if i == class_arr.index('Class A') else 0 for i in range(0,len(class_arr)) ]
```

Comment: This appears to do the reverse of what was requested.